# Can I override a virtual function with a pure virtual one?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual, language-lawyer, pure-virtual

I have three classes: `B`, `D` and `G`.  `D` is a `B` and `G` is a `D`.  Both `B` and `D` are abstract.  `B` is from a third party.

`B` has a non-pure, virtual method that `G` needs to implement (to be a `D`).  Can I **and is it good practice to** redefine/override a virtual function to be pure virtual?

Example:

```
class B // from a third party
{
public:
   virtual void foo();
};

class D : public B
{
public:
   void foo() override = 0; // allowed by gcc 4.8.2
   virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class G : public D
{
public:
   // forgot to reimplement foo
   void bar() override;
};

int main()
{
   G test;  // compiler error is desired
}
```

To the question of "can I?" gcc allows it, but I do not have the terms/vocabulary to verify the behavior is part of the standard or is undefined and happens to work today.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You asked:

> Can I override a virtual function with a pure virtual one?

The answer is: Yes, you can. From the C++11 standard:

> **10.4 Abstract classes**
>
> 5 [ *Note:* An abstract class can be derived from a class that is not abstract, and a pure virtual function may override a virtual function which is not pure. —*end note* ]

Comment: I didn't really understand the answer. Is the method `foo()` in G pure virtual, or not?

Comment: @BЈовић, yes. `foo` is pure virtual in `G`.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile the code with a more modern compiler then you'll get the following error messages that explain the problem

```
prog.cc:23:6: error: variable type 'G' is an abstract class
   G test;  // compiler error is desired
     ^
prog.cc:10:9: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'G'
   void foo() override = 0; // allowed by gcc 4.8.2
        ^
1 error generated.
```

As for the Standard then (10.3 Virtual functions)

> 11 A virtual function **declared in a class** shall be defined, **or
>   declared pure** (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is
>   required (3.2).

Comment: Yes, I desire that error (if this whole paradigm is supported by the compiler and seems reasonable to other programmers).

Comment: @jtooker However as it follows from the compiler messages gcc 4.8.2 behaves differently.

Comment: "No diagnostic is required".  Does that mean the compiler is allowed to accept this without error?  If so, what will the compiled code do?

Comment: @PieterNuyts The program will be ill-formed.