# Is it valid to override virtual function with pure specifier?

Tags: c++, overriding, language-lawyer, pure-virtual

*Note: I do not ask whether or not this is reasonable thing to do or if this is good design. I'm just asking if this is well-defined behaviour and if the results are as expected.*

I came upon a following class hierarchy:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B: public A
{
    void foo() override 
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo()\n";
    }
};

struct C: public B
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct D: public C
{
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "D::foo()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* d = new D;
    d->foo(); //outputs "D::foo()"
    // A* c = new C; // doesn't compile as expected
}
```

Is this code well defined? Are we allowed to override definition with pure-specifier?

Comment: Maybe, you can add the tag [language-lawyer] since it's about language specification ?

Comment: I guess you cannot instantiate `C` if it's abstract. On the other hand, I would say overwriting and overwriten function is not a good practice, in which case would you use this?

Comment: @MartinMorterol Added, thanks!

Comment: @Ivan I'm afraid it already exists in our code, it got past our code review unfortunately. I just wonder if this is okay thing to do (and what it actually is doing).

Comment: I was wondering in this question if it is actually valid to `override` pure virtual functions like it is done here in `struct B` and found  that this seems indeed good practice - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446652/is-there-any-point-in-using-override-when-overriding-a-pure-virtual-function/46448798

Comment: Dup of [Can I override a virtual function with a pure virtual one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526666/can-i-override-a-virtual-function-with-a-pure-virtual-one) and [Turning a non-pure virtual function into pure in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585033/turning-a-non-pure-virtual-function-into-pure-in-a-subclass) etc.

Comment: Huh, I can close my own question by voting to close and then agreeing with that vote, interesting... Thanks for the links @LanguageLawyer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[[class.abstract/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.abstract#5) of the current draft Standard:

> [*Note:* An abstract class can be derived from a class that is not abstract, and **a pure virtual function may override a virtual function which is not pure**. — *end note*]

The very same note is included even in the *C++11 Standard*. So, the answer is **yes, it is valid**.